# Coordinating conjunctions, consequences of actions, and commas

Tags: commas, coordinating-conjunctions

I've managed to completely confuse myself by thinking myself in circles. I know that when a coordinating conjunction joins two independent clauses (unless they're particularly short), you need to use a comma before the conjunction.

I was under the impression that if the two clauses are closely related, such as being the consequence of an action, you shouldn't use (or at least don't need) a comma. Every time I try to search (here and Google), though, I just get general results for coordinating conjunctions, so I'm having trouble getting clarification.

For example:

> Let me know if you have any other issues, and I'd be happy to help.
> Reach back out to us, and we will respond quickly.
> Let us take care of your comfort needs, and you'll have a climate control system that works like a charm.

In each of these sentences, you wouldn't have the second independent clause if the first doesn't happen, so my instinct is that there shouldn't be commas before "and." Is this correct? Can someone point me in the direction of where I'd find the rules for this type of situation?

Comment: There are no "rules" here. All your example commas are ***optional** stylistic choices*. The only guiding *principle* is you should probably include a comma *as a courtesy to the reader* if the preceding clause is so long it's possible the reader might otherwise have trouble parsing the text. But don't insult the reader, and bear in mind that the modern style is increasingly towards less and "lighter" punctuation (downgrade some periods to commas, and discard some commas completely).

Comment: The comma is useful when the first clause ends with a noun, so the reader isn't temped to think that "and" is separating two nouns, as in "let us take care of your needs and wants". The comma signals that it's a conjunction between clauses.

Comment: I'd use the comma in all 3 examples, although conjunctions other than **and** would add more meaning. Never heard that the relationship thing affected the comma. **As** I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Pace @Yosef Baskin, to my eye the commas in all of OP’s examples are distracting and out of place. Again, it’s a stylistic choice.

Comment: Do you see any of those examples as correct English? 'Let me know if you have any other issues, and I'd be happy to help' does not need that comma, and is not correct English. 'Reach back out to us, and we will respond quickly' isn't exactly wrong but it is unidiomatic and it does not need that comma. 'Let us take care of your comfort needs, and you'll have a climate control system that works like a charm' is smarm, not English and again, it does not need that comma.